# Autodesk Forge Viewer - PixelCompare extension - how to show measurements in compared documents

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Is there some way how to show measurements in compared documents - compared using new Pixel Compare extension? In previous version of Autodesk Forge Viewer there was [custom extension](https://github.com/wallabyway/2DCompare) that allowed this (see screen below) - it was possible to draw measurements in overlay mode with highlighted differences in blue and red. I need something similar - see differences in blue and red and be able to measure and see measurements directly in this diff (like on picture).

Pixel compare extension works fine but shows the differences in a different layer than the measurements. I tried to load 2 models into viewer and align them - it works fine, but I need to render differences highlighted in red/blue.

[Image - Measurements and differences in one layer - older custom extension 2DCompare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmz4f.png)

I need to draw the differences to a measurement layer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the *official* PixelCompare extension never supported measurements.

Let me report this request to the viewer engineering team, and if there's sufficient demand, we could consider adding this feature.

Alternatively, consider contacting the author of the custom extension, and see if it could be upgraded to work well with the latest version of the viewer.